# Birt mongodb param

Tags: mongodb, parameters, birt

I installed Birt 4.3 (latest) as Eclipse plugin.
JDBC as data source works perfectly for me. I define a param in query. I can define a param in data set via Report Design and link it to a report param.

But I have multiple issues with MongoDB

1) When I open "edit data set" dialog I cannot find the menu "Parameters" in left side. I only see

```
Data Source
Query
Output Columns
Computed Columns
Filters
properties Binding
Setting
Review Results
```

No Parameter any more. I can see it in JDBC not in MongoDB
Could anyone please how to define a parameter in data set while Data source is MongoDB? How to link the param to the param of report?

2) In MongoDB (Birt) how to define a parameter in the expression of "Run Database Command" or in query
In JDBC we can use "?" as a param holder like

```
select * where id=?
```

param will replace "?"

For MongoDB

```
{
    runCommand : {
        aggregate : COLLECTION_NAME,
       .....
    }
}
```

`COLLECTION_NAME` is vary. How can I represent it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB expression syntax itself does not support parameters, thus the MongoDB ODA connector does not support data set parameters directly. You can use BIRT scripting to reference a BIRT report parameter and change the runtime value of the "Command expression" data set property.

You can identify the system connection when you make a MongoDB data set using Eclipse. This is in the MongoDB Collection area of the data set dialog.

Check http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/628348/ for more information.

EXAMPLE

You can use script to set the query using a beforeOpen script in the dataset such as:

```
this.queryText ='{ "findQueryExpr" : "{ pop: { $gte: 20000  } }" , "operationType" : "FIND" , "collectionName" : "zipcode" , "selectedFields" : [ "_id" , "city", "pop"]}'
```

The fields and collection name need to match the pre-configured dataset.

Replace the 20000 with your parameter value. For example, using a parameter named "Population" which takes an integer, you can update your query at run-time with the following script:

```
this.queryText ='{ "findQueryExpr" : "{ pop: { $gte: '+params["Population"].value+'  } }" , "operationType" : "FIND" , "collectionName" : "zipcode" , "selectedFields" : [ "_id" , "city", "pop"]}'
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, can you summarize the answer from the forum, the link stays as a reference, but this way if the other site goes away the answer here will still have value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. MongoDB expression syntax itself does not support parameters but BIRT did support (it replaced text at run-time. I don't remember the version but it was in 2011). It had the parameter menu as JDBC. BTW Jasper supports parameter in MongoDB. I wonder why I cannot see the parameter menu in MongoDB as JDBC. The parameter menu in MongoDB was supported in earlier version. Does anyone have the experience or solution?