# BIRT Standalone Application for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, reporting, birt

Did someone ever use BIRT API in their customize application?.I am trying to make an application for my mongoDB database. But i have no clue from where to start as I am totally new to reporting. I have set the environment with eclipse and BIRT. 
Now if anyone can point me from where to start, that would be a lot of help to me. 
Any advice, how to reach this goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install BIRT Designer at
   http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/.
2. Then make a new report project.
3. Then make a new, blank report.
4. In the BIRT Designer Data Explorer tab, add the MongoDB Data Source
   and configure and test your connection to it. See
   [Birt mongodb param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024375/birt-mongodb-param/) for
   some examples of queries for MongoDB using BIRT.
5. In the BIRT Designer Data Explorer tab, add a data set and organize
   the data you want to pull from the MongoDB data source you just
   created.
6. Add a report item to your report... table, chart.
7. Run the report.

Optionall use BIRT Designer Pro to make data objects that you can use across reports, dashboards and mobilize with a REST API.