# How to create BIRT Report with Mongodb dynamic queries

Tags: mongodb, report, birt

I want to get report for a month with certain parameters. I have tried many times with different ways to generate Birt report with mongodb dynamic query.

but option to set dynamic params is not given in birt for mongodb dataset.
I followed few ref as well. Still no luck

[Birt mongodb param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024375/birt-mongodb-param/)

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/628348/

I need help, how to set dynamic params like dates, ids etc in BIRT dataset with mongodb..

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, found right way to play with parameters in BIRT mongoDB dataSet.

Go to DataSet > property Binding > write in query text in below format:

'{ "findQueryExpr" : "{ _id: { $lte:'+params["id"].value+'   } }" , "operationType" : "FIND" , "collectionName" : "customer" , "selectedFields" : [ "_id" , "customerType", "customerNumber"]}';

above solution solved my problem.